# Using Proguard with Android without obfuscation

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, dalvik

I am getting an error "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" when using the -dontobfuscate flag. Otherwise my app exports fine. I don't want to obfuscate because I am using BugSense for error tracking and they charge $99 a month if you need to de-obfuscate your stack traces. I still want to get the file size and optimization benefits of proguard.

If I comment out -dontobfuscate every thing works great. Except for the unreadable stack traces.

my progaurd.cfg file:

```
-dontobfuscate
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

I will also accept an answer that points me in the right direction. Is there a log file I should be looking at?

Answer (score 42):

Add `!code/allocation/variable` is workaround for ProGuard bug when `-dontobfuscate` is set to your `-optimizations`

For example

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable
```

Comment: yes, looks like `-dontobfuscate` needs `!code/allocation/variable`

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that you are using the latest version of the Android SDK or at least the latest version of ProGuard (version 4.7 at this time of writing) inside the SDK (android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar).

Comment: It could be a bug either in ProGuard or in the dex tool. If you can provide a sample that allows to reproduce the problem, on the ProGuard bug tracker, I'll look into it.