# Android Proguard - dontobfuscate doesn't disable obfuscation

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

a question on android proguard obfuscation.
For some reason, when generating apk using ant, I want proguard to shrink size (remove unused classes) but no name obfuscation. In `proguard.cfg`, I added:

```
-dontobfuscate
```

all others in `proguard.cfg` are either `-dontwarn` or `-keep class`. But after decompile the generated apk (`dex2jar`), I found many names are still obfuscated. Why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Just found this post solves my issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651703/using-proguard-with-android-without-obfuscation
Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Since nobody was actually answering this, here is the link to the post that solves the issue: [Using Proguard with Android without obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651703/using-proguard-with-android-without-obfuscation)

Basically, what you need to add below your `-dontobfuscate` instruction is:

`-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable`

Important thing here is: `!code/allocation/variable`