# Cannot run project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I was trying to run my project in Android Studio, I got the following error message

```
Execution failed for task ':CricHQ:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/19.0.1/dx -JXmx4g --dex --output 
Error Code:
2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Cannot merge new index 66514 into a non-jumbo instruction!
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.jumboCheck(InstructionTransformer.java:108)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.access$800(InstructionTransformer.java:25)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer$StringVisitor.visit(InstructionTransformer.java:71)
    at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.callVisit(CodeReader.java:114)
    at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.visitAll(CodeReader.java:89)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.transform(InstructionTransformer.java:48)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformCode(DexMerger.java:840)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformMethods(DexMerger.java:811)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassData(DexMerger.java:783)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassDef(DexMerger.java:680)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:540)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

Anyone can help me with this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a limitation in Android on the number of Java methods you can have in a single dex file, and you're hitting that limit. Unfortunately, there's no easy solution to it. Your choices are:

- Simplify your code. If you're using a lot of libraries, see if you can cut back on the number of libraries you're using. Some libraries have a lot of methods in them.
- Use ProGuard even in your debug builds. ProGuard will strip out unused methods and can save a lot of space. To get started on ProGuard, look at these links:

  - http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard
  - For debug builds, you probably don't want ProGuard to obfuscate your class and method names -- it will make life much more difficult. You'd like it to just do its dead code stripping. This question will have you some pointers: [Using Proguard with Android without obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651703/using-proguard-with-android-without-obfuscation)

If those approaches don't work, it's possible to split your application into multiple dex files and use classloader tricks to make it work at runtime, but that's more complicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. After I removed a lib from the project, it  becomes fine to compile and run.

Comment: Can you give me more information about how to use ProGuard in debug builds?

Comment: _"If those approaches don't work, it's possible to split your application into multiple dex files and use classloader tricks to make it work at runtime, but that's more complicated."_ even more complicated than proguard? unbelievable.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html -- basically you need a custom class loader, and you have to be careful about how you split classes between individual dex files so that all the dependencies work out, provided it can be done at all.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using Android Studio without gradle then Preferences->Compiler->Android Compilers->Force Jumbo Mode

If your using gradle then add to build.gradle

```
android {
    dexOptions {
       jumboMode true
    }
```

Comment: I added the above configuration into `build.gradle`, but still no luck :(. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try to set incremental = true and javaMaxHeapSize “4g” dexOptions.

Comment: the incremental and max heap size settings worked for me thanks @jeraldo