# Android studio: Gradle build finished with error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley, build.gradle

I have been using Android Studio and I am getting this error when trying to build.I can't able to proceed.

This is the error in Android Studio:

```
    Executing tasks: [:libraries:facebook:generateDebugSources, :library:generateDebugSources, :volley:generateDebugSources]

    Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
    WARNING [Project: :volley] "testPackageName" is deprecated (and will soon stop working); change to "testApplicationId" instead
    :libraries:facebook:preBuild
    :libraries:facebook:preDebugBuild
    :libraries:facebook:checkDebugManifest
    :libraries:facebook:prepareDebugDependencies
    :libraries:facebook:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :libraries:facebook:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :libraries:facebook:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :libraries:facebook:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :libraries:facebook:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :libraries:facebook:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :libraries:facebook:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :libraries:facebook:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :libraries:facebook:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :libraries:facebook:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :libraries:facebook:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :library:preBuild
    :library:preDebugBuild
    :library:checkDebugManifest
    :library:prepareDebugDependencies
    :library:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :library:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :library:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :library:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :library:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :library:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :library:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :library:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :library:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :library:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :library:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :volley:preBuild
    :volley:preDebugBuild
    :volley:checkDebugManifest
    :volley:prepareDebugDependencies
    :volley:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :volley:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :volley:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :volley:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :volley:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :volley:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :volley:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :volley:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :volley:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :volley:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :volley:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
```

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 7.494 secs

This is my app gradle :

build.gradle :

```
        apply plugin: 'android'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 11
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0'
        }
        signingConfigs {
            release {

            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
        compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.2.4'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0+'
        compile project(':libraries:facebook')
        compile project(':library')
        compile project(':stripe')
        compile project(':volley')
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile files('libs/activation.jar')
        compile files('libs/mail.jar')
        compile files('libs/iprint.jar')
    }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717885/cannot-run-project-in-android-studio

Answer (score 3):

This Question is old but it may be useful for new programmers of Android Studio  ,
So this error in my case solved by cleaning project from Build Menu.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you post all error's text, in my case in the end will be very useful information to fix this trouble. Maybe in your case trouble is the same.

So, in my case was trouble with dependecies.
In my app module in **build.grale** I used other dependencies for support.v4

In your case: *compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'*

Facebook SDK used **jar**, so, support.v4 was added as jar.

To fix this, just remove jar, and add to your **Facebook** **build.gradle** file the same line to import support library as on your main app module.

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue today

This is a bug in dex merger when the dex files that are being merged have more than 65536 methods (or strings). We can fix this by adding

dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

In the gradle file. Don’t forget to add this all sub projects too else it may not work.

Comment: Thankyou ,But I have make some correction in my question

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in ubuntu 16.04 and came up with a simple solution:

Type `sudo nautilus` in terminal.

Now go to the root directory and recursively change permissions to Read and Write and Create and Delete files. You will be able to do that by the option Change permissions for enclosed files.